# Cursor stuck in a board using ncurses (programming SOS game)

Tags: c, cursor, ncurses

I am programming the S-O-S game. and I was using `printf` to print the board and letters with slashes or/and hyphens. I had a problem when I was told that I had to use `printf` to print the previous symbols in color depending on the player (player 1=red and player 2=yellow). With `printf` you cannot print symbols in the same line in different colors (you could, but the code will be huge).

I started to use ncurses with the `mvprintw` function and then everything went bad.
I had the cursor stuck in the last column and line of the board, which disturbed the program's good behavior.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0iuw.png)

The above image is when I entered "f7" and letter "S" (and the column h is not working, everything is shifted to the left).

This is the program that prints the board with the `main` function:

```html
void printboard(sos *jg){


  //my_win = create_newwin(25, 50, 0, 0);
  
 
 int row,col;  /* to store the number of rows and */
 int num=1;
 int let=97;
 /*the number of colums of the screen */
 
 //while (getch()!= '\n'){
     /* start the curses mode */
 start_color();
 
 init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
 init_pair(2, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
 curs_set(2);
 
 
 for(row=1;row<35;row++){
  mvprintw(1,1,"+",0);
  if((row-1)%4==0) mvprintw(row,1,"+",0);
  for(col=2; col<66;col+=8){
    mvprintw(0,col,"   %c  ",let-8);
    if(row<34){
     if((row-1)%4==0) mvprintw(row,col," - - - +",0);
     if((row-1)%4==1) {
     mvprintw(row,col-1,"|",0);
     mvprintw(row,65,"|",0);
     }
     if((row-1)%4==2) {
     mvprintw(row,col-1,"|",0);
     mvprintw(row,65,"|",0);
     mvprintw(row,0,"%d",num/8);
     mvprintw(row,66,"%d",num/8);
     num++;
     }
     if((row-1)%4==3) {
     mvprintw(row,col-1,"|",0);
      mvprintw(row,65,"|",0);
     }
    }
   mvprintw(34,col,"   %c  ",let-8);
   let++;
  }  
  }


 for(row=1;row<35;row++){
  for(col=2; col<73;col+=8){
    if(row<34){
     if((row-1)%4==1) {
     if(jg->L[row/4][col/8] & NW_MASK){
                                                if(jg->L[row/4][col/8]==jg->C[row/4][col/8]){
                                                        attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                                                        mvprintw(row/4,col/8,"\\",0);
                                                        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                                                }
                                                else {attron(COLOR_PAIR(2)); mvprintw(row/4,col/8,"\\",0);attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));}
                                        }
                                        if( jg->L[row/4][col/8] & N_MASK){
                                                if(jg->L[row/4][col/8]==jg->C[row/4][col/8]){
                                                        attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                                                        mvprintw(row/4,col/8,"|",0);
                                                        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                                                }
                                                else {attron(COLOR_PAIR(2)); mvprintw(row/4,col/8,"\\",0);attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));}
                                        }
                                        if( jg->L[row/4][col/8] & NE_MASK) {
                                                if(jg->L[row/4][col/8]==jg->C[row/4][col/8]){
                                                        attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                                                        mvprintw(row/4,col/8,"/",0);
                                                        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                                                }
                                                else {attron(COLOR_PAIR(2)); mvprintw(row/4,col/8,"\\",0);attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));}
                                        }
     }

     if((row-1)%4==2) {
     mvprintw(row,col-5,"%c",jg->V[row/4][col/8]);
                                        move(200,100);
                                        //printf("%c\n",jg->V[row/4][col/8]);
    }
     if((row-1)%4==3) {
     }
    }
  }
  
 }




 //printf("\n");


 //}
 //move(100,100);
 //getch();
 refresh;
}




int main(){
 sos jg, *pjg;
 pjg=&jg;
 int action=0,move=0, count=0,check=0;
 num_player player=JOGADOR1;
 InitGame(pjg);
 initscr();
 noecho();
 
 while(count<64){
  printboard(&jg);
  while(action!=1){
   move=GetPlayerMove(player);
   action=CheckAndSetMove(&jg, move, player, action); // return 0 for no , 1 for yes
  }
  check=CheckSequence(&jg, move, player);
  if(check==0) player++;
  printboard(&jg);
  action=0;
  count++;
  check=0;
 }
 

 endwin();

 return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any type of help!

EDIT: here you have a link to the full code https://github.com/Zaregtyp/SOS-game

Comment: The `refresh;` at the bottom can't be working for you, it should be called as `refresh();`

Comment: Sorry yes, I added it manually here because it erased itself manipulating the copy/paste. But it is well written in my program.

Comment: It's not really clear from your description what the problem is, and this code isn't complete enough to test.

Comment: I tried to put the code using the tool for it but it doesn't work.
Here you have the link to have access to the whole code : https://github.com/Zaregtyp/SOS-game

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you're mixing curses with stdio -- they really don't go together. Try changing `scanf` to `scanw` and see what happens.

Comment: I have started my function PrintBoard from scratch and it works now, but I am still struggling with colors printing. If player 1 makes a point, the links must be printed in his color and same for player 2. I don't know if my function UpdateDirInfo is well done for a Bit Wise type of code. (or if once again PrintBoard is not doing a good job). Once again everything is here : https://github.com/Zaregtyp/SOS-game